# How do I add a library which doesn't contain JARs to Java project?

Tags: java, json

I created a Java project in which I want to add JSON library. I searched in the JSON library but it doesn't contain JARs.

I downloaded the JAR files and it worked, but still I don't know how to add a library without JARs to a Java project?

Comment: How you add libraries depends on how you build your project. It differs between eclipse and netbeans, and if you use ant or maven it is different again.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by json library that doesn't contain any jars. Why dont you take a look at jackson, gson that are written in java and help you work with json files.

Comment: yees @Axel im using eclipse with ant and Maven.how can i add this library?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to [Webjars](http://www.webjars.org/). They provide jars for several web libraries around.